# Laravel Eloquent whereHas Issue using With

Tags: laravel

```
$data['orders'] = OrderReturn::with(['order_detail.products','order_detail.products.Companies'])
                              ->whereHas('order_detail',function($query){
                                 $query->where('status','lifted');
                              })
                             ->where('customer_id',hashids_decode($id))
                             ->where('status','lifted')
                             ->get();
```

WhereHas not working here but if i use whereHas inside the with it works like this

```
$data['orders']=OrderReturn::with(['order_detail.products','order_detail.products.Companies','order_detail'=>function($query){
                $query->where('status','lifted');
            }])
            ->where('customer_id',hashids_decode($id))
            ->where('status','lifted')
            ->get();
```

what is the problem with first one?

Comment: Are you looking for inner join?

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Too many results? Too few results? Error? Note that the 2nd one differs from the 1st in that the 2nd one filters the relationship based on the condition (meaning you get less related models) while the first one filters the first model based on a relationship condition (meaning you potentially get less `OrderReturn`  models)

Comment: `order_detail` is relationship. you can not use `whereHas`  outside `with` . This is a logic

Comment: I just wanna set the condition if order_detail status is lifted then fetch the record only.